# Get browser cookie in native Android application

Tags: android, cookies

I've opened mobile application which offer referral program (e.g. send link to friend and you will get 5USD once user installed the application).

So I share link `www.helloworld.com/refcode=cod1` with my friend via email. My friend open application in webBroswer(let it be chrome), get redirected to play market, downloaded and opened app.

Eventually I've received bonus as expected.

Just wondering how this referral program suppose to work in Android. How they tracked him ?

Even if they install cookie in webbrowser (chrome), I doubt that this cookie can be accessed outside of the browser in mobile application due security reasons.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-android-deep-linking-google-play-referrer

They are passing referral parameter to Play Market

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the following:

They need some unique ID of your friend Android. Then when he asked for the application from the browser this ID should be saved on the server together with the ref code. When app will start it should send such ID again to the server and then you will receive 5USD. This Id may be the phone IP address supposing that all these operations will not take while and IP is not changed. To prevent hacking they may set some timeout for this action (10 min).

From the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

> For obvious security reasons, your application has its own cache,
>   cookie store etc.—it does not share the Browser application's data.

Comment: Was thinking that they may track IP, however it does not looks like very reliable.

Comment: Any way I am believe they don't use a local data from the browser

Comment: There are some native mechanisms from Google - https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/ But the app which I was asking for did not use them.  However it's not clear how these invites from Google supposed to work